# How can I add the data I pulled from Firebase with React js to the list?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

How can I add the data I pulled from Firebase with React js to the list? Images are attached. Then I need to write a function to send notifications to the tokens in the list.

```
const tokenList = [];
 <div className="flex">
  <div className="flex items-center mt-2 mb-2">
 <select onChange={selectProvince}>
 <option>Lütfen İl Seçiniz</option>
{Provinces.map((entry, index) => {
return (
   <option key={index} value={entry.il}>
{entry.il}
 </option>
  );
  })}
 </select>
  </div>
  <div className="flex items-center pl-2 mt-2 mb-2">
  <select onChange={selectDistrict}>
<option>Lütfen İlçe Seçiniz</option>
{!!province &&
province.ilceleri.map((ilceleri, index) => {
return (
<option value={ilceleri} key={index}>
{ilceleri}
 </option>
);
})}
</select>
</div>
</div>

 {Object.keys(data).map((id, index) => {
if (
!!province &&
data[id].driverCurrentPosition.province === province.il &&
!!district &&
data[id].driverCurrentPosition.district === district
) {
return (
// tokenList.concat({id:  index + 1, token : data[id].token}) );
```

Here, I want to list the incoming token (data[id].token) data when the if condition is valid and delete it when the process is finished.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I shared as you wanted. thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure if I understand the problem/question though. If you step through this code in a debugger line by line, and check the value of each variable, what is the first line of the code that doesn't do what you expect it to do?